# Not allowed to edit resolv.conf on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, resolv.conf

I'm trying to edit the resolv.conf file on my ubuntu 16.04 instance, but I'm unable.

Here are the first two lines of the file:

```
 # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
 #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Please help me to find out how to fix it.

Edited: Here's the entire file

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 62.210.16.6
nameserver 62.210.16.7
search online.net
```

I'm trying to edit this file to connect my domain to this server. Any type of edits in this file is overwritten with the exact same lines.

It is a fresh new installation and yes I'm using "sudo".

Comment: Permissions for files in /etc/ will be your first problem, if you use `sudo` to elevate your privileges you can edit the file. The warning is real though, if you reboot, or restart networking that file is re-created and any changes will be lost.

Comment: You don't tell us what your problem is. Is this ALL that's in /etc/resolv.conf? When did the problem start? Etc.

Comment: See if `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` is where your current nameservers and search domains are being defined. Also check `/etc/network/interfaces`. Report back to @heynnema or I may miss your comment.